# Abort trap 6 error in C - mac terminal

Tags: c

I'm learning C and recently I was trying some tutorials from youtube, and I was running this code, but it doesnt work I don't know why... when i run it on Terminal, gives an error "Abort trap: 6"

I was following this tutorial : https://youtu.be/7F-Q2oVBYKk?list=PL6gx4Cwl9DGAKIXv8Yr6nhGJ9Vlcjyymq

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


int main ()
{
  char name[15] = "John Snow";
  printf("My name is %s\n", name);

  name[2] = 'z';                   
  printf("My name is %s\n", name);

  char food[] ="pizza";
  printf("The best food is %s \n", food);

  strcpy(food, "bacon");
  printf("The best food is %s \n", food);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: You should do poor mans way of debugging and assign and print one line at a time, and see which line gives the error.

Comment: It seems that there is no problem.

Comment: I compiled, linked, ran the code with no changes on ubuntu lilnux 16.04 and it worked perfectly.

Comment: This code is fine. You might have made a typo or something.

Answer (score 4):

The error means you are writing to memory you don't own. Will likely happen if you try to copy a string longer than the one you specified for food ('pizza'). In this case it could be cos you are copying the string into memory location assigned to a string constant.

try this instead:-

```
char *food = malloc(sizeof(char)*6); 
strcpy(food, "pizza"); 
printf("The best food is %s \n", food); 

strcpy(food, "bacon");`
printf("The best food is %s \n", food);
```